# Syntax issue with Procedures in 11g

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have a problem with running below procedure in oracle 11g because of the JSON value feature not available in 11g. Can you please help in correcting the procedure.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE             "STANDARDIZE_ADDRESS" 
(
  JSON_DOC IN VARCHAR2
, JSON_OUT OUT VARCHAR2
) is
    CNTRY_IN VARCHAR2(100);
    STATE_IN VARCHAR2(100);
    CITY_IN VARCHAR2(100);
    LAT_IN VARCHAR2(100);
    LONG_IN VARCHAR(100);
    SOURCE VARCHAR2(100);

    COUNTRY_NAME VARCHAR2(100);
    COUNTRY_ID RAW(16);
    STATE_NAME VARCHAR2(100);
    STATE_ID RAW(16);
    CITY_NAME VARCHAR2(100);
    CITY_ID RAW(16);
    REGION_ID RAW(16);

    MAP_COUNTRY VARCHAR2(100);
    MAP_STATE VARCHAR2(100);
    MAP_CITY VARCHAR(100);

    COUNTRYSEQ NUMBER;
    UNK_REGION RAW(16);

    OUTPUT_STR VARCHAR2(3000);

    QUOTE_REPLACE VARCHAR2(4);
BEGIN
    QUOTE_REPLACE := 'zqzq';
    UNK_REGION := HEXTORAW('00000000000000000000000000000000');

    -- Parse values from JSON
    select json_value(json_doc,'$.Country'),
           json_value(json_doc,'$.State'),
           json_value(json_doc,'$.City'),
--         json_value(json_doc,'$.Latitude'),
--         json_value(json_doc,'$.Longitude'),
           json_value(json_doc,'$.Source')
        into cntry_in, state_in, city_in, source 
        from dual;

    -- Any blanks get treated as "None" (so there are no null entries in DB
    CNTRY_IN := NVL(CNTRY_IN,'none');
    STATE_IN := NVL(STATE_IN,'none');
    CITY_IN  := NVL(CITY_IN,'none');
    SOURCE   := UPPER(NVL(SOURCE,'unknown'));

    -- Check to see if passed in address matches Master data
    BEGIN
        -- Query against standard list
        select COUNTRYNAME, COUNTRYID, STATENAME, STATEID, CITYNAME, CITYID
            into COUNTRY_NAME, COUNTRY_ID, STATE_NAME, STATE_ID, CITY_NAME, CITY_ID
            from STANDARDLIST_VIEW
            where (CountryName = CNTRY_IN or CountryCode = UPPER(CNTRY_IN))
              and StateName = STATE_IN
              and CityName = CITY_IN;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Using Standard Data');
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            -- Replace special characters and Standardize case of data
            if (LENGTH(CNTRY_IN) > 2) then
                -- INITCAP function does not correctly case the character after an apostrophe.
                CNTRY_IN := REPLACE_SYMBOLS(REPLACE(INITCAP(CNTRY_IN),chr(39)||'S',chr(39)||'s'));
            else
                -- Two characters are assumed to be CountryCode
                CNTRY_IN := REPLACE_SYMBOLS(UPPER(CNTRY_IN));
            end if;

            -- INITCAP function does not correctly case the character after an apostrophe.
            STATE_IN := REPLACE_SYMBOLS(REPLACE(INITCAP(STATE_IN),chr(39)||'S',chr(39)||'s'));
            if (LENGTH(STATE_IN) = 2 and (UPPER(CNTRY_IN) = 'UNITED STATES' or UPPER(CNTRY_IN) = 'US')) then
                -- Special case of US States are upper case 2-character, not title-cased
                STATE_IN := UPPER(STATE_IN);
            end if;

            -- INITCAP function does not correctly case the character after an apostrophe.
            CITY_IN := REPLACE_SYMBOLS(REPLACE(INITCAP(CITY_IN),chr(39)||'S',chr(39)||'s'));

            BEGIN
                -- Check mapping data to see if this has been translated to standard values
                select stdcountry,stdstate,stdcity
                    into MAP_COUNTRY, MAP_STATE, MAP_CITY
                    from GEO_MAPPING_VIEW
                    where upper(srccountry) = upper(CNTRY_IN)
                      and upper(srcstate) = upper(STATE_IN)
                      and upper(srccity) = upper(CITY_IN);

                -- If we found a match use this data for lookup, else use our cleaned up data
                CNTRY_IN := MAP_COUNTRY;
                STATE_IN := MAP_STATE;
                CITY_IN  := MAP_CITY;

                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Found Mapped Data');
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN OTHERS THEN
                    -- don't worry about error.  Use cleaned up data for building Non-Stand entries
                    COUNTRY_ID := null;  -- dummy statement to trap error
            END;

            BEGIN
                -- Query against standard list
                select COUNTRYNAME, COUNTRYID, STATENAME, STATEID, CITYNAME, CITYID
                    into COUNTRY_NAME, COUNTRY_ID, STATE_NAME, STATE_ID, CITY_NAME, CITY_ID
                    from STANDARDLIST_VIEW
                    where (CountryName = CNTRY_IN or CountryCode = CNTRY_IN)
                      and StateName = STATE_IN  -- (StateName = STATE_IN or StateCode = UPPER(STATE_IN))
                      and CityName = CITY_IN;

                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Using Mapped/Cleaned Data');
            EXCEPTION
                -- Build out table entries based on what's missing
                WHEN OTHERS THEN
                    -- Query Country table by CountryName/CountryCode
                    BEGIN
                        select COUNTRYNAME, ID
                            into COUNTRY_NAME, COUNTRY_ID
                            from MASTER_COUNTRIES
                            where CountryName = CNTRY_IN or CountryCode = CNTRY_IN or CountryISO3Code = UPPER(CNTRY_IN);
                    EXCEPTION
                        WHEN OTHERS THEN
                            -- If record not found, Create Country entry
                            COUNTRY_ID := null;
                            COUNTRY_NAME := CNTRY_IN;

                            -- select ID into REGION_ID from MASTER_REGIONS where REGION = 'NAM';
                            REGION_ID := UNK_REGION;
                            select SYS_GUID() into COUNTRY_ID from dual;
                            -- Create value for CountryCode (starts at 10; iso3 issequnce value + 900)
                            select SEQ_COUNTRYCODE.NEXTVAL into COUNTRYSEQ from dual;

                            insert into MASTER_COUNTRIES (ID, COUNTRYCODE, COUNTRYISO3CODE, COUNTRYNAME, REGIONID, NONSTDSOURCE, NONSTDDATE, LASTMODIFIED)
                            values (COUNTRY_ID, to_char(countryseq), to_char(countryseq + 900), COUNTRY_NAME, REGION_ID, SOURCE, SYSDATE, SYSTIMESTAMP);

                    END;        

                    -- Query State table by StateName and CountryID
                    BEGIN
                        select STATENAME, STATEID
                            into STATE_NAME, STATE_ID
                            from MASTER_STATES
                            where StateName = STATE_IN
                              and CountryID = COUNTRY_ID;
                    EXCEPTION
                        WHEN OTHERS THEN
                            -- If record not found, Create State entry
                            STATE_ID := null;
                            STATE_NAME := STATE_IN;

                            select SYS_GUID() into STATE_ID from dual;

                            insert into MASTER_STATES (STATEID, STATENAME, COUNTRYID, NONSTDSOURCE, NONSTDDATE, LASTMODIFIED)
                            values (STATE_ID, STATE_NAME, COUNTRY_ID, SOURCE, SYSDATE, SYSTIMESTAMP);

                    END;        

                    -- Query City table by CityName and StateID
                    BEGIN
                        select CITYNAME, CITYID
                            into CITY_NAME, CITY_ID
                            from MASTER_CITIES
                            where CityName = CITY_IN
                              and StateID = STATE_ID;
                    EXCEPTION
                        WHEN OTHERS THEN
                            -- If record not found, Create City entry
                            CITY_ID := null;
                            CITY_NAME := CITY_IN;

                            select SYS_GUID() into CITY_ID from dual;

                            insert into MASTER_CITIES (CITYID, CITYNAME, STATEID, NONSTDSOURCE, NONSTDDATE, LASTMODIFIED)
                            values (CITY_ID, CITY_NAME, STATE_ID, SOURCE, SYSDATE, SYSTIMESTAMP);

                    END;

                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Creating Non-Standard Data');
            END;
    END;

    -- dbms_output.put_line(json_doc);

    -- Build JSON Output
    output_str := '{"Country":{"Name":"' || COUNTRY_NAME || '","ID":"' || RAWTOHEX(COUNTRY_ID) || '"},' ||
                  '"State":{"Name":"' || STATE_NAME || '","ID":"' || RAWTOHEX(STATE_ID) || '"},' ||
                  '"City":{"Name":"' || CITY_NAME || '","ID":"' || RAWTOHEX(CITY_ID) || '"}}';


    -- dbms_output.put_line(cntry_in||','||state_in||','||city_in||','||source);
    -- dbms_output.put_line(country_name||','||country_id||','||state_name||','||state_id||','||city_name||','||city_id);

    json_out := output_str;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
    json_out := '{}';
END;
```

Comment: What is wrong with the procedure?  Can't you install the json package?

Comment: take a look at this, it should be avail for 11g, although you might need to upgrade APEX first -
 but then you'll have a json parsing solution https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_json.htm#AEAPI29635

Answer (score 0):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer generated from comments left by the question author](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

I was able to create a script to parse the JSON objects without using JSON or APEX JSON packages.

```
DECLARE 
ln_1 INT;ln_2 INT; ln_3 INT; ln_4 INT;
ln_Comma_1 INT;ln_Comma_2 INT; ln_Comma_3 INT; ln_Comma_4 INT;
SELECT INSTR(JSON_DOC,':',1,1),INSTR(JSON_DOC,':',1,2),INSTR(JSON_DOC,':',1,3),INSTR(JSON_DOC,':',1,4)
,INSTR(JSON_DOC,',',1,1),INSTR(JSON_DOC,',',1,2),INSTR(JSON_DOC,',',1,3),INSTR(JSON_DOC,',',1,4)
INTO ln_1,ln_2,ln_3, ln_4, ln_Comma_1,ln_Comma_2,ln_Comma_3,ln_Comma_4
from Dual;

SELECT SUBSTR(JSON_DOC,ln_1+1,(ln_Comma_1-ln_1)-1),
SUBSTR(JSON_DOC,ln_2+1,(ln_Comma_2-ln_2-1)),
SUBSTR(JSON_DOC,ln_3+1,(ln_Comma_3-ln_3-1)),
SUBSTR(JSON_DOC,ln_4+1,10)
INTO cntry_in, state_in, city_in, source
FROM Dual;
```